# Cleveref displays ?? 3.2.2 instead of the correct reference name

Tags: errors, cleveref

I'm trying to use cleverref for my references but up to now it does not work for me. Currently my setup looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

This is some text containing a self-reference \cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

This yealds:

```
This is some text containing a self-reference ??.
```

Latex tells me:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `test' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.
```

And when I run it a second time (just using `pdflatex test.tex`):

```
LaTeX Warning: \Cref reference format for label type `' undefined on input line 14.
```

I already tried to set the language globally by putting `ngerman` into `\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman] ..` and also tried `german` and even `english` instead with no effect.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you try compiling twice?

Comment: What do you mean with compiling twice? I'm using latexmk for building and already tried to delete all .aux-files and everthing else within the build directory but that had no effect. Did you mean that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, I added a minimal example that compiles and has the same effect.

Comment: @cgnieder that should be an answer :)

Comment: Changing package order according to cgnieder solved that problem partly. In the minimal example from above it now works for me. In my bigger project I now dot not get the `??` anymore. But I still do not get the german translations. I again tried setting `german` or `ngerman` globally (in the `\documentclass`) or locally (in the corresponding `\usepackage`).

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the package loading order. `varioref` should be loaded before `hyperref` and `cleveref` needs to be the last of the referencing related packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

This is some text containing a self-reference \cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this now works for the minimal example above - but not for a bigger project I'm just working on. Unfortunaly I cannot paste the whole code here so you could try that out. I do not get the `??` anymore. But I'm not able to make it use german language for the `\cref`. It tried setting the language to `ngerman` and `german` globally (in the `documentclass`) as well as as options to `varioref` and `cleveref`. I'm still getting `section xyz` instead of `Abschnitt xyz`.

Comment: @MathisHoffmann The active language in the document is the _last_ one passed to `babel` (except if you change it explicitly, e.g., with `\selectlanguage`). But that's nothing to do with `cleveref`.

Comment: If you load `\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}` then `cleveref` uses German captions even if you don't load `ngerman` with `babel` or even if you don't load `babel` at all

Comment: That's excactly what I tried and what works for me in the small test file - but not in a bigger project I'm working on.. :(

Comment: @MathisHoffmann then you _need_ to reduce your bigger file down to a minimal working example still showing the behaviour although it loads `\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}`. Obviously the example posted doesn't truely reflect what you're doing in your larger file...

Comment: Ok, while reducing the project a found the problem (but not yet a convincing solution). I'm using `\foreignlanguage{english}{here some english text}` in my project and after that the references are handled in english, which I think should only happen in between the `{}`, right. I can reset that after every call to `\foreignlanguage` by appending `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` but this looks more like a hack than a convincing solution..